# Connect to URL using java socket

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, stomp

I have a STOMP websocket server accepting connections on localhost:8080/price-stream/ws

I am attempting to connect using the [Gozirra library](https://github.com/pedroteixeira/gozirra) which uses java.net.socket to connect, but the new Socket() method only accepts host and port parameters. Connection code [here](https://github.com/pedroteixeira/gozirra/blob/master/src/main/java/net/ser1/stomp/Client.java#L48) . Is there a way to define the full resource location in the socket parameters, to include the price-stream/ws location?

```
Client c;
    try {
        c = new Client("localhost", 8080, "guest", "guest");
        c.subscribe("topic/pricechannel1", new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void message(Map headers, String body) {

                System.out.println(body);
            }

        });
        c.unsubscribe("topic/pricechannel1"); // Unsubscribe all listeners
        c.disconnect();
    } catch (LoginException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Failing that, is there a way on the server-side I could forward a request for a Spring websocket connection? In other words, my server is a Spring webapp running on tomcat. Is there a way I could forward requests to the root of my server i.e. localhost:8080 in this case, into a specified resource location in tomcat. I am not very well versed in linux server configuration but I assume it is possible with some tweaking. Thanks

Comment: No. There is no way to define the resource location in the Socket parameters. Resource locations are part of HTTP, not TCP. Why aren't you using an HTTP API? Rolling your own HTTP client code is fraught with peril.

Comment: I was attempting to use SSE but really I need bi directional communication. The price-stream data is already used in a browser so I was hoping to re use the existing server to transmit to a Swing GUI, and also add some channels for the Java GUI to use. Would you suggest this is a bad idea and that really I should use a standard socket for java -> java communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Spring 4.2 StompClient to connect to my host here is the code:

```
WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
stompClient.setMessageConverter(converter);
StompSessionHandler handler = new WSClient(); //custom implementation
String url = "ws://{URL}/ws/websocket";
stompClient.connect(url, handler);
```

Then configured my WSClient class to subscribe to the channel after a connection is established.

```
session.subscribe("{channel name}", new StompFrameHandler() {
```